# How to list only the latest revision of all nodes in a view?

Tags: views, workflows, nodes

I currently have a view that lists all of our nodes which is what we use for a content dashboard. It shows the most recently updated nodes, their workflow status, and a few other details.

The problem we seem to be having is that we're using Revisioning which creates a new pending revision each time a user updates a node. When a user updates a node, the workflow state (custom CCK field) switches to **Review** automatically. Since the current published node has the workflow state **Live**, the view's workflow field does show "Review". I'm assuming this is because the view is only pulling the currently published content and not the pending revisions content.

When using the view type **Node Revisions** it lists every revision of a node, not just the latest one. This is a problem because our dashboard would be filled with a single node's revision history instead of all the current nodes.

Is it possible to create a view that lists only the latest revision (pending, or current) of all nodes on our site?

**Version info**
Drupal 6.22
Views 6.x-2.12

Answer (score 2):

In the view you should have it sort by revision id (vid) descending, then use [Views Group By](http://drupal.org/project/views_groupby) to group by node id (nid).